# I lost all my work on Git using a reset using the GUI tool, is there a way to restore my files?

Tags: git, github

Attached screenshot to show what I mean. [image: 12-07-2012 to 02-02-2013] I've lost all my work in between those two dates using the GUI tool and not sure how to recover them. Can anyone help please?

**Git Log**

```
commit eb64161f29fff57ab861880c4cd1cdf7641c39bf
Author: unknown <DIAMONS@DIAMONS-PC.(none)>
Date:   Fri Dec 7 02:00:10 2012 -0500

A

commit e7850a9c4218b8853b95fff72b08d81c9de1a493
Author: unknown <DIAMONS@DIAMONS-PC.(none)>
Date:   Fri Dec 7 01:59:09 2012 -0500

A

commit 76c81938af7ec183a306e5377ad503b84371dbc7
Author: unknown <DIAMONS@DIAMONS-PC.(none)>
Date:   Fri Dec 7 01:57:27 2012 -0500

A

commit a98041150974116addf1edb867c3481140a16633
Author: unknown <DIAMONS@DIAMONS-PC.(none)>
Date:   Fri Dec 7 01:56:23 2012 -0500

A
```

**Git Reflog**

```
eb64161 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from fe2772d3a363fc7ca348d936bd3a5ac97ccf9dc2
fe2772d HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from 096491742d37c885ed93db2bb06b3fbe65b69499
0964917 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 6eb9a8e66561d2e72b8391fec823df6d6999cceb
6eb9a8e HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to 6eb9a8e
eb64161 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from 4d6a18311433a9bee737eda9bf6114f8bc35fa2c
4d6a183 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from 13a4a7e00c15986e07c48969f026afb2fe02f60b
13a4a7e HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from 4374fecebf215eb868beb881af8909922d45e764
4374fec HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from 49f004a3d08ee52ee24334c07fc9d35c40480dbb
49f004a HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from 8e58a900f13132e0dcaa39ae980f7868184cbf65
8e58a90 HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from 60299f452350c05d22e6bd703f1a7658112c171f
60299f4 HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from 7e1ae4e7907f446d7d238741933509d4d64e071
7e1ae4e HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from bec6e9bab96300e4a5d11b5fb1f381659bffe16
bec6e9b HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from 60299f452350c05d22e6bd703f1a7658112c171
60299f4 HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from 4d6a18311433a9bee737eda9bf6114f8bc35fa2
4d6a183 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from eb64161f29fff57ab861880c4cd1cdf7641c39b
eb64161 HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from master to eb64161
eb64161 HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from 4d6a18311433a9bee737eda9bf6114f8bc35fa2
4d6a183 HEAD@{17}: checkout: moving from master to HEAD@{3}
eb64161 HEAD@{18}: checkout: moving from eb64161f29fff57ab861880c4cd1cdf7641c39b
eb64161 HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from master to master@{2013-01-19}
eb64161 HEAD@{20}: pull: Fast-forward
4d6a183 HEAD@{21}: checkout: moving from 7e1ae4e7907f446d7d238741933509d4d64e071
7e1ae4e HEAD@{22}: checkout: moving from 60299f452350c05d22e6bd703f1a7658112c171
60299f4 HEAD@{23}: checkout: moving from 8e58a900f13132e0dcaa39ae980f7868184cbf6
```

Comment: Have you installed git console? If yes, can you do a `git log` and `git reflog` and show the output?

Comment: Your git reflog doesn't show any reset command applied. Now I am not sure if you do something in the UI it would be recorded in the reflog, let me double check on that and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not delete commits and other objects instantly. So if your data was commited, you can get them by checking out last good commit.

Walk thru that reflog you posted and checkout each version (it starts from newest). sooner or later you will find a good version with your data. Then mark that commit as a branch (`git checkout HASH -b my-lost-master`).

**Edit 1:**

Another option is to run `git fsck --lost-found` and check it's output in the same way as reflog.

**Edit 2:**

Yet another rescue tool is this:

```
git rev-list --objects --all \
| awk '{cmd="git cat-file -t "$1;cmd |& getline t; printf("%s %-7s %s\n", $1, t, $2); close(cmd);}' \
| less
```

It will scan entire git object storage and describe all in there. You should see your files somwhere in that long list.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't find anything. There are specific files that I can't find which I only added recently. I use Heroku to host my site and I had to rollback the release to fix my site.

Comment: I force pushed a bad copy of the repo.

Comment: Force push do not delete anything, you only lose reference to head (the latest commit). That's why we have `git reflog` command, which shows local history of branches (where and when they pointed to).

Comment: I was using Heroku, so a force push overwrites everything in the git repo. Anyway, I resolved the issue by contacting support.